# Restrict the viewable part of a tile to a polygon area in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, geojson

In Leaflet, how does one restrict the viewable part of a tile to the area contained within a polygon (or geojson), i.e., the intersection between a polygon and the tile beneath.

**Example use**: display only one country and hide all others.

EDIT: I'm not looking for the fitBounds/setMaxBounds method but for a way to display only the inner area of a polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `map.setMaxBounds(L.latLngBounds)` method to restrict the view.

For restricting the map view:

```
map.fitBounds(polygon.getBounds()); // max zoom to see whole polygon
map.setMaxBounds(polygon.getBounds()); // restrict map view to polygon bounds
map.options.minZoom = map.getZoom(); // restrict user to zoom out
```

When you want to revert this:

```
delete map.options.maxBounds;  // remove the maxBounds object from the map options
map.options.minZoom = 0; // set min-zoom to 0 = no restriciton
```

I have setup a jsfiddle where you can see the behaviour: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LsvDk/)

**EDIT:**

I have updated the jsfiddle to use a multipolygon and hide all of the world except this triangle. The only problem is that during zoom you can still see other parts of the map.
[jsfiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/LsvDk/2/)

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm asking. I'd like to restrict the tile to your blue triangle, i.e., the only visible part of the map is the triangle with the rest cropped. Much like the intersection between the polygon and the map.

Comment: okiharaherbst, have a look at my edit, is this what you want?

Comment: that'll do just fine for my case, much obliged! I suppose one could restrict the zoom to avoid seeing the other parts of the world.

Comment: Btw, I stumbled upon https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas which is Leaflet plugin that does just that too.

Comment: that plugin looks promising, feel free to write this as the answer

Comment: Thanks but your multipolygon solution is a no brainer that requires no other dependencies. That'll fit the bill for now.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but for others looking, the [Leaflet Boundary Canvas](https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas) layer may do what you need. You can pass it a polygon or multipolygon, and it will obscure all other areas of the map.