# Restrict the viewable part of a Leaflet tile to a polygon area

Tags: r, leaflet, polygons

I am learning how to use R and Leaflet.  I am almost done making a map using California counties, but I don't like that I can see other states in the map.  I would like to white out the map around my polygon (the counties).  I saw a similar problem resolved elsewhere but I don't know enough to apply what was said there to my code.  Could someone check this code out and suggest what I need to add?

If you scroll to the bottom of this link you'll see what I am trying to do.  http://rpubs.com/stefanya/127436

The code I am using is:

```
#loading shapefile
  counties <- readOGR("./shapefiles", layer="cb_2014_us_county_20m")

#filtering for only california
  counties <- subset(counties, counties@data$STATEFP=="06")

#making a leaflet map of california counties
  leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons(data=counties)

#merging the data into this shapefile
  counties@data = data.frame(counties@data,     sumByCounty[match(counties@data[,"NAME"], sumByCounty[,"NAME"]),])  

#set color palette
  colorRamp <- colorRamp(c("#2c7fb8","#7fcdbb","#edf8b1"), interpolate = "spline")
  palette <- colorNumeric(colorRamp, counties@data$progress)

  leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite") %>%
addPolygons(
  weight= 2,
  stroke = TRUE,
  fillOpacity = .65,
  data=counties,
  color = ~palette(progress),
   popup = ~paste("<strong>County:</strong>",NAME,
                   "<br>",
                   "<strong>Total Responses:</strong>",sumByCounty,
                  "<br>",
                   "<strong>Complete:</strong>",progress,"<strong>%</strong>")
  ) %>% addLegend(title = "Response <br> Goal Met", pal = palette, values = counties@data$progress, bins=5, opacity = 1, position="topright", labFormat = labelFormat(suffix = '%'))
```

Comment: A simply workaround would be to build a big polygon over other States to hide them…

Comment: You can perhaps make up your own custom tile. https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/136/how-do-i-render-my-own-maps-for-my-website

Comment: Is this the link to the "similar problem solved elsewhere": http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73048/how-do-i-clip-osm-basemap-with-a-polygon because its basically @ghybs workaround, and could be applied to leaflet easily enough.

Comment: I think this is probably a bad idea anyway, since lots of useful text labels and other annotations will get clipped and the map will look a bit ugly. What's wrong with giving the user a bit more context?

Comment: downvote for not giving a reproducible example - how about something that uses one of the standard shapefile sets supplied with one of the R spatial packages?

Comment: Thank you folks, I'm sorry I am so new to this and having trouble understanding!  The other similar question is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456115/restrict-the-viewable-part-of-a-tile-to-a-polygon-area-in-leaflet

Comment: I think you are right about the map looking off if the text labels are concealed.  I thought I'd play around with different tiles to see if there was a way to avoid concealing important text.  I am just against including extraneous information in my graphics if it is at all avoidable.

Comment: If I just use a shapefile, I will lose the ability to zoom in and see basic city info, right?  I think this is why I opted to go the Leaflet route.  Thanks for your patience and help!

Answer (score 1):

Create a polygon with with two rings, the first with geometry of the entire earth (or your view's bounds), the second with the geometry of California:

```
[
    // World
    [[90,-180], [90,180], [-90,180], [-90,-180]],
    // California
    [[42.006186,-123.233256],[42.011663,-122.378853],[41.995232,-121.037003],[41.995232,-120.001861],[40.264519,-119.996384],[38.999346,-120.001861],[38.101128,-118.71478],[37.21934,-117.498899],[36.501861,-116.540435],[35.970598,-115.85034],[35.00118,-114.634459],[34.87521,-114.634459],[34.710902,-114.470151],[34.448009,-114.333228],[34.305608,-114.136058],[34.174162,-114.256551],[34.108438,-114.415382],[33.933176,-114.535874],[33.697668,-114.497536],[33.54979,-114.524921],[33.40739,-114.727567],[33.034958,-114.661844],[33.029481,-114.524921],[32.843265,-114.470151],[32.755634,-114.524921],[32.717295,-114.72209],[32.624187,-116.04751],[32.536556,-117.126467],[32.668003,-117.24696],[32.876127,-117.252437],[33.122589,-117.329114],[33.297851,-117.471515],[33.538836,-117.7837],[33.763391,-118.183517],[33.703145,-118.260194],[33.741483,-118.413548],[33.840068,-118.391641],[34.042715,-118.566903],[33.998899,-118.802411],[34.146777,-119.218659],[34.26727,-119.278905],[34.415147,-119.558229],[34.40967,-119.875891],[34.475393,-120.138784],[34.448009,-120.472878],[34.579455,-120.64814],[34.858779,-120.609801],[34.902595,-120.670048],[35.099764,-120.631709],[35.247642,-120.894602],[35.450289,-120.905556],[35.461243,-121.004141],[35.636505,-121.168449],[35.674843,-121.283465],[35.784382,-121.332757],[36.195153,-121.716143],[36.315645,-121.896882],[36.638785,-121.935221],[36.6114,-121.858544],[36.803093,-121.787344],[36.978355,-121.929744],[36.956447,-122.105006],[37.115279,-122.335038],[37.241248,-122.417192],[37.361741,-122.400761],[37.520572,-122.515777],[37.783465,-122.515777],[37.783465,-122.329561],[38.15042,-122.406238],[38.112082,-122.488392],[37.931343,-122.504823],[37.893004,-122.701993],[38.029928,-122.937501],[38.265436,-122.97584],[38.451652,-123.129194],[38.566668,-123.331841],[38.698114,-123.44138],[38.95553,-123.737134],[39.032208,-123.687842],[39.366301,-123.824765],[39.552517,-123.764519],[39.831841,-123.85215],[40.105688,-124.109566],[40.259042,-124.361506],[40.439781,-124.410798],[40.877937,-124.158859],[41.025814,-124.109566],[41.14083,-124.158859],[41.442061,-124.065751],[41.715908,-124.147905],[41.781632,-124.257444],[42.000709,-124.213628],[42.006186,-123.233256]]
]
```

Example on Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/ZWzuxz/preview